# How do i make a correct architecture for a multi-enterprise application?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, architecture, server, enterprise

I've got a question about the architecture for a JEE application, which is supposed to give personal spaces in the server (and a database) for enterprises that make an account with us.

Is it better if I create a new database for each enterprise or should I put them all in the same database?

I'm currently using Spring Boot, Spring JPA Hibernate, Thymeleaf, MYSQL.
(I'm also having an android side to connect with my Servlets)

Should I stick with these or is there something better?